# Password authentication failed when setting up gitlab

Tags: postgresql, gitlab

I've been following the installation guide for GitLab:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

And it has been working great unitl I got to step "Initialize Database and Activate Advanced Features". When i run:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get the following errors:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "git"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "git"
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:6:in `connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:28:in `drop'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:114:in `drop'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:128:in `block in drop_current'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:278:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each_current_configuration'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:127:in `drop_current'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:131:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/setup.rake:17:in `setup_db'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/setup.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:122:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Couldn't drop gitlabhq_production
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "git"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "git"
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:6:in `connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:15:in `create'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:278:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each_current_configuration'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:217:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:215:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:215:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:217:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:215:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:215:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:132:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/setup.rake:17:in `setup_db'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/setup.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rake:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:122:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"gitlabhq_production", "pool"=>10, "username"=>"git", "password"=>"secure password", "host"=>"localhost"}
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "git"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "git"
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:648:in `connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:664:in `block in method_missing'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/home/git/gitlab/db/schema.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/schema.rb:41:in `instance_eval'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/schema.rb:41:in `define'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/schema.rb:61:in `define'
/home/git/gitlab/db/schema.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:221:in `load_schema_for'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in `block in load_schema_current'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:278:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each_current_configuration'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `load_schema_current'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:237:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:241:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:132:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/setup.rake:17:in `setup_db'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/setup.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Essentially, it fails on the password authentication. However, I can run:

```
sudo -u git -H psql -d gitlabhq_production
```

Without any problems. I can even specify the -W flag to force password notification. I can enter any password and it will still let me in. My gitlab/config/database.yml contains:

```
#
# PRODUCTION
#
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gitlabhq_production
  pool: 10
  username: git
  password: "secure password"
  host: localhost

#
# Development specific
#
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gitlabhq_development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: "secure password"
  host: localhost

#
# Staging specific
#
staging:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gitlabhq_staging
  pool: 10
  username: git
  password: "secure password"
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: gitlabhq_test
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
  host: localhost
  prepared_statements: false
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by setting the password for git using:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
ALTER USER git WITH PASSWORD '<some password you want>';
```

I then changed the password in the database.yml to the same password:

```
sudo -u git -H nano /home/git/gitlab/config/database.yml
```

**EDIT:** typo

Comment: typo: sudo -u postgres pslqg -> sudo -u postgres psql